# React-hook-form: Trigger field validation through all field array items

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a field array like this:

```
const { append, remove, fields } = useFieldArray<CampaignFormValues, 'assortmentNeeds'>({
  name: 'assortmentNeeds',
})
```

And `assortmentNeeds` has the following values:

```
export interface AssortmentNeeds {
  campaignId: string
  productGroup?: string
  category?: string
  demand?: number
  demandRatio?: number
}
```

Now when one `demandRatio` value changes, I want to trigger the validation for all `demandRatio`s of all items of the field array.

So, ideally I'd like to have something like this in a hook:

```
const { trigger, control } = useFormContext<CampaignFormValues>()

const assortmentNeeds = useWatch<CampaignFormValues, `assortmentNeeds.${number}`>({
  name: `assortmentNeeds.${index}` as const,
  control,
}) as AssortmentNeeds

useEffect(() => {
  trigger('assortmentNeeds.0...10.demandRatio')
}, [trigger, assortmentNeeds.demandRatio])
```

But of course `0...10` is not a valid index. How can I trigger the `demandRatio` field of all field items?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: According to the creator if the library a foreach is fine: https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/discussions/5576#discussioncomment-857892